# Retrieve Assembly Version of an Application stored in an msi

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

I cant work out how I would tell from the installer msi, what AssemblyVersion of the application it will install is.

I would like to make a request every few hours to a network location, check the setup.msi to detect a change and then prompt the user to update.

Could I tether the two AssemblyVersions, so as I increment the application it increments the Installers? That way I could check the installer Version?

Or, is there a way to tell from the msi what application version it will install?

Or should I just go about this in a different way, say placing a text file with the revision number on the network share? (not preferred)

N.B. I have used `SetupProject` to create my installer.

Comment: It seems you are looking for ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: unfortunately I am moving away from ClickOnce deployment

Comment: You can [extract msi](https://superuser.com/questions/307678/how-do-i-extract-files-from-an-msi-package) package. But it would be better if you create a file containing version information and use it ti determine if there is a newer version.

Comment: Could you just make the setup name include the assembly version? `MyApp_1.0.2.msi`? Depends on your build process. How do you invoke the install of the newer version? Could you make that invoke script smarter so it grabs the latest file? It could do so even by last modified file date for MSI files (no version number checking necessary).

Comment: @Stein Note that changing the name of the msi file interferes with minor upgrades.

Comment: thanks @Michael, have given some good advice. Hopefully I now have what I need to create a working solution. Will update tomorrow

Comment: Yes, true for minor upgrades - I always assume major upgrades are used in the real world - because of minor upgrade limitations. IMHO this file name problem is one of the worst ones for real release work. Who needs several setups all named `setup.msi`? Beyond version, what about languages? I guess you could go `Eng.msi` and `Ger.msi`, etc... I think the inability to set a proper output file name is a key reason why major upgrades are used so pervasively. I think name + culture + version + architecture should be visible in the file name. Maybe. There could be more, such as OEM name, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of repeating some of Michael U's answer, I'll point out that nobody does that in a Windows Installer environment. When any of the files in a Visual Studio MSI build need deploying to clients, the only solution with VS setup projects is a major upgrade, where you increment the version of the setup project (accept the changes), set RemovePreviousVersions to true, and you must increment the file versions of the files that need updating. You don't need to change AssemblyVersion to do this, but you do need to increment AssemblyFileversion. This should help:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/

but it's missing the part about updating file versions.

In general, the update mechanism is fairly straightforward. Major upgrades are based on UpgradeCode, so your application just needs to do a web service call somewhere passing the current ProductVersion and UpgradeCode, and then you need to download any version that is higher than your current ProductVersion, then install it. That's the general idea that works for multiple products on a client system, and there are simpler solutions if you know there is only one product.

Comment: thanks Phil, a very helpful post. Do you think this would be possible without a webservice call? Since the application is aware of its product version, could I extract the product version of an installer msi from a network share and compare the two?

Comment: If your app can reach anywhere and see if there is a new version that will work, yes, I was thinking it's more common to call over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm speaking generally about Windows Installer here, because I'm not deeply familiar with SetupProject.)

You could certainly tie versioning information of both an msi and the assemblies contain if your build system supports it, and if you limit your assembly versions to those that are representable as a [ProductVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370859). Note that if you want to use Windows Installer upgrade logic, you must have meaningful changes alter the first three fields, as Windows Installer ignores the fourth.

If you can crack open the .msi file to perform your own logic (say with Windows Installer APIs, or wrappers such as DTF), you should be able to read the assembly version from the metadata stored within the msi database. In particular, you will want to read values from the [MsiAssemblyName table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370062) or the [File table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596). Note that the MsiAssemblyName table contains assembly versions and the File table contains file versions; those values are only synchronized if you have ensured it.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an older question, I tried to solve this in VB .net and came up with the following solution. Would this help?

B.t.w. this code checks for the version number of the MSI file, which can be set in the SetupProject file (see properties), but i.m.o. this version should be the same as the project/solution contained in the setup project.

```
    Private Function checkVersionAssemblyInMsiFile(filename As String) As String
Try
    Dim WindowsInstaller = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

    Dim Database = WindowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenDatabase", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, WindowsInstaller, {filename, 0})
    Dim Query = "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'"
    Dim View = Database.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, Database, {Query})
    View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, View, Nothing)
    Dim Record = View.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, View, Nothing)
    Dim Version = Record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData", Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, Record, {1})

    Return Version

Catch ex As Exception
    Return Nothing
End Try
```

End Function